# Best way to package and deploy MVC3 applications at client sites

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, obfuscation

What is the best way to deploy an MVC3 application to a client site?  Now I can create a deployment package using web deploy and possibly give them a script to deploy the files on their IIS servers.  But is there any other way?  I just want to give them a one-click option after they download the application, if that makes sense.

Also, is there a good way to obfuscate MVC3 application as a whole?

Comment: The obfuscation question is a separate question entirely. I recommend removing it. I also recommend searching the site for previous questions on the topic, not asking it in a new question. It has been covered  a lot. Perhaps someone can link to such a question for you...

Comment: Here's a link to a search for obfuscation questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mvc+code+obfuscation

Comment: That's a good question Francois.  I have to assume they don't want to be worrying about the nitty gritty.  Hence the reason for asking for a one-click option, if at all possible

Comment: @Cpat, Ouch, wanted to edit my comment and clicked delete. Yes, regarding my IIS comment. If the site requires a lot of configuration in IIS including installation then the clients would need to know what they are doing. If they don't want to do that then you might need to write a elaborate script to deal with all that or remote access and install/configure IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a script to deploy your MVC application files, as well as the MVC required DLLs to the web server.  In your script you can have it so that it creates the application in IIS to the appropriate application code.

As for a "One Click" type deployment, you'll have to have some knowledge of how their IIS is setup and what they are willing to do with virtual directories.

Comment: So does that mean that there isn't really a good one-size-fits-all one-click option I could use with an MVC3 application at all?  That is what I was worried about.

Comment: @Cpat There's really not.  But you could always create an "installer" application that manipulates IIS to create the virtual directory and register the application and move the DLLs.

Comment: Any links you can provide to do the above @Shark?

Comment: I used to use InstallShield in the past. Publish your web app to a folder on your hard-drive. Then create an installer package, which also will create target folders, etc. Then automatically run a script which will configure IIS. When I used to use Installshield it had all those options to run custom scripts and check for minimum requirements such as OS version, is IIS installed, is .NET installed, etc. It even let you include things like .NET so it could install it if the right version wasn't found. I'm sure VS2010 setup projects can achieve the same these days.